# oracle initialization or shutdown in progress error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

While I am trying to connect to my Oracle 11g DB, I am getting error "ORA-01033: oracle initialization or shutdown in progress error". To resolve this I am following following steps:

SQL> connect / as sysdba

SQL> shutdown abort

SQL> startup nomount

SQL> alter database mount;

SQL> alter database open;

But when I am executing "alter database open" command, I am getting another error - ORA-00333: redo log read error block 15472 count 3189.

I found out that we can resetlogs to fix this so I tried 
ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS; -- it gives an error that we can use RESETLOGS only after incomplete database recovery.

I am seeking help to resolve this issue and to find out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your redo log file is corrupted. It's required to clear redo log.....

You can follow following steps for the same:

Assuming that your database is on mount state and login as a sys with sysdba privilege:

alter system set "_allow_resetlogs_corruption"=true scope=spfile;

shutdown immediate;

Again, login as a sys with sysdba privileges(i.e. sqlplus sys as sysdba)

startup mount;

alter database open resentlogs;

recover database until cancel; --Here, you need to press  when it prompts to specify a log.

alter database open resetlogs;

startup;

alter system set "_allow_resetlogs_corruption"=false scope=spfile; --Reverting back and bouncing the db for applying the changes.

shutdown immedaite;

startup;

Comment: If you do this, you will have most likely lost transactions, it is highly recommended to recreate the database at this point.....

Comment: @steve - In the context of ORA-00333, most likely chance to loose transactions followed by respective REDOLOGs if you don't have database in archive log mode.

In case of not having archive log and getting ORA-00333 error, recreating oracle DB also will not solve the problem by various means (i.e. recovering the database).

Comment: worked for me, but the DB had trouble accepting the command for allow resetlogs corruption, I guess either it's easy to misspell, or something else

Answer (score 0):

try this pls:

connect /no log

(((connect with SYS user))

shutdown immediate

((start service in windows services))

alter database open

recover database using(logfile)